# How to send Push Notification to just one device using Urban Airship?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, push-notification, urbanairship.com

I have my app in Appstore and it has Urban Airship Push notification implemented.

I need to send some test messages to my device only using Urban Airship Push. 
How do I do that?

Thanks!

Comment: There should be a way to find out the TokenID generated for your device and then you need to only push the notification for that particular TokenID from server side.

Comment: That is where the confusion is :) How to detech TokenID for our device? Any idea?

Comment: I think what @Allen.Qu has mentioned in his answer is perfect. Please look into it. Hopefully that would solve your doubt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get it like this:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken
{
NSString *tokenStr = [[deviceToken description] substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(1, 71)];
NSString *result=[tokenStr stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
NSLog(@"deviceToken result:%@",result);
}
```